# Is it possible to run a program as a subprocess of an AppleScript program without a Dock icon?

Tags: macos, applescript, subprocess

I want to run Firefox with some special parameters and I wrote an AppleScript program to that end which simply runs said command. However, if I click run my program Firefox starts with its own icon in the Dock. Is it possible to start Firefox in a subprocess instead so that it uses the icon of my AppleScript program.

Answer (score 2):

No. When you "tell application" anything that application will launch. That's the way it works because the application actually performs the task. They only way around it is to not require a separate application. In your case you may be able to use the command line program curl to perform tasks over the web. But without seeing any code or knowing what you're trying to do, I can't suggest how you might use curl.